# Redirect user by IP in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

So I've been trying to complete some construction on my website. However, I want it so that if a user does not match my IP, they will be redirected to a "under construction" page. However, I want this IP match to work for all of the pages on domain.com, except for the under construction one.

Is there a way that I can add a function like this in .htacess in the root folder of my website?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule !^/?under_construction.html /under_construction.html [L,R]
```

Where **12.34.56.78** is *your* IP address and **/under_construction.html** is your under construction page. You'll need to make sure there are no other htaccess files in subdirectories that use mod_rewrite (as it would supercede these rules).